Amazon Pay Magento 2.3.5-p2
Magento 2.3.5-p2
I had two instances in the past two weeks where an Order came through my Magento Store from the same address using Amazon Pay.
In my Amazon Pay account there are no signs of funds or transactions. I have contacted Amazon Pay support and they did not see anything on their end.  I do speculate this is some sort of frud orders or a glitch in Magento. There is no name associated with these orders but the same billing and ship to address in NY. Two different IP addresses, one in MA and the other in Sweden.
My question is how can an order come through on the backend of Mangento with no payment or transcation on Amazon. You never see a payment come through unless there is a proceesed payment transaction.
Anyone see this kind of action. Amazon support is no help

It appears that you're experiencing an issue where orders are being created in Magento without corresponding transactions in Amazon Pay. Here are a few steps to troubleshoot and potentially resolve this issue:
Verify Payment Module: Ensure that the Amazon Pay module is correctly configured and up to date. Sometimes module updates can fix bugs.
Check for Magento Glitches: Review Magento's logs (var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log) for any errors or warnings that might indicate a problem during the order creation process.
Review Payment Gateway Response: Check if there are any network or API issues between Magento and Amazon Pay that might cause a discrepancy.
Suspicious Activity: Given the same shipping address and different IPs, this could be fraudulent activity. Implement additional security measures such as CAPTCHA during checkout, address verification, and IP logging.
Consult Developer Logs: If you have developer logs or custom logging in place, review them to see if there are any anomalies during the order processing.
If these steps do not resolve the issue, consider hiring a Magento expert to perform a deeper investigation. This might involve looking into custom code, third-party modules, or potential security vulnerabilities.

How do you go about getting an updated version. I show Module Version: 3.4.1 currently installed.
